# Join query where row_number +1

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, row-number

My table contains rows, where [time_start] > [time_end]
I want to rewrite the query so that the values [time_start] and [time_end] displayed correctly as shown below.

```
14, 2022-03-16, 2022-03-16 23:30:33.000,    2022-03-17 00:36:52.000
14, 2022-03-17, 2022-03-17 23:31:00.000,    2022-03-18 00:59:38.000
14, 2022-03-18, NULL                        ,NULL
14, 2022-03-19, 2022-03-19 23:30:51.000,    2022-03-19 23:38:05.000
```

I tried to connect via ROW_NUMBER, but I need to take into account the +1 row condition above.
How can this be resolved?
Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#tmp_time](
    [num_wf] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dt] [date] NULL,
    [time_start] [datetime] NULL,
    [time_end] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[#tmp_time] ([num_wf],[dt],[time_start],[time_end])
VALUES (14, '2022-03-16',   '20220316 23:30:33',    '20220316 01:23:40')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#tmp_time] ([num_wf],[dt],[time_start],[time_end])
VALUES (14, '2022-03-17',   '20220317 23:31:00',    '20220317 00:36:52')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#tmp_time] ([num_wf],[dt],[time_start],[time_end])
VALUES (14, '2022-03-18',   NULL,               '20220318 00:59:38')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#tmp_time] ([num_wf],[dt],[time_start],[time_end])
VALUES (14, '2022-03-19',   '20220319 23:30:51',    '20220319 23:38:05')

select t1.[num_wf], t1.[dt], t1.[time_start], t2.[time_end]
from (
    select [num_wf],[dt], [time_start]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [num_wf] ORDER BY [dt], [time_start]) as rn_start
    from [dbo].[#tmp_time]
)t1
LEFT JOIN (
    select [num_wf],[time_end]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [num_wf] ORDER BY [dt], [time_end]) as rn_end
    from [dbo].[#tmp_time]
)t2 ON t1.[num_wf]=t2.[num_wf] AND t1.[rn_start]=t2.[rn_end] --AND t1.[time_start] < t2.[time_end]
```

Comment: I don’t understand time start being greater then time end. How is that possible?

Comment: Don't really understand your issue here. But you can probably use `LEAD()` or `LAG()` to achieve what you want

Comment: Or are you just trying to screen out null time values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will gives you the expected result.

It uses `LEAD()` window function to obtain the next row `time_end` value

```
select *,
       new_time_end = CASE WHEN [time_start] IS NULL
                           THEN NULL
                           WHEN [time_end] < [time_start]
                           THEN LEAD([time_end]) OVER (PARTITION BY num_wf 
                                                           ORDER BY dt)
                           ELSE [time_end]
                           END
from   #tmp_time
```